# I'm looking for some Clipper Decompiler

Tags: dos, decompiling, clipper

I have very old DOS program, it was made 20 years ago in Clipper. I need to make some little modification. Ofc I tried Decompiling to ASM, but code looks horrible.

Comment: The question and answer assisted me thanks. Would you by any chance know how to recompile a Clipper program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention the Clipper version, but on [Vetusware (the biggest free abandonware downloads collection in the universe)](http://vetusware.com/download/Rescu5%20and%20Secure5%20deCompiler%20for%20Clipper%205/?id=5692) you can find a decompiler for version 5, dated 1994.
It might suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago I had one called "Clipper Decompiler" or "Unclipper" and its internal protection was:

- put in several places on your code, before compiling, this: `ERRORSYS=0987654321`

and no one will decompile your code with "unclip"